# Always getting HTTP response code 503 when accessing webpage

Tags: java, https, http-status-code-503

I made an application that could read a webpage as HTML. It worked just fine up until about a week ago when it started receiving HTTP response code 503 every single time. It doesn't matter if I change how often I try to read by adding delays, it still fails. I can access it just fine in a web-browser (I use Firefox Browser 100.0.2 64-bits), and it never has anything like Cloudflare.

I have tried to search for solutions but have found absolutely nothing beyond *the server is overloaded, add some delays* or similar advice (and most of it is 5+ years old at least). Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Here is the method I used to access webpages. Worked like a charm for over a year, until it just stopped a week ago or so...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

...other code...

public static final String readPage(final String httpsURL) {
    try {
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty ("User-Agent", 
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0");
        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(inputLine + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch(Exception failure) {
        if(failure instanceof IOException) throw (IOException) failure;
        else throw new IOException("Unknown failure!", failure);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if this method will work if you make one call? I think this is due to the protection of the site from parsing, if so, then I can only help

Comment: @BorisIvanov The method used to work if you made a single call. It also worked for many calls. Now, however, it does not work; a single call or many, it fails in both cases

Comment: Can you try to make a  single call from another IP address? This is most often due to IP address blocking. If this is the cause of the problem, then I will give you a solution that will help you avoid it. Please let me know

Comment: Can the problem really be IP blocking when I can access the same website through my browser (from the same computer)? If I can type the URL into Firefox and access the site just fine, then it shouldn't be IP blocking that's stopping me from accessing it through Java, right?

Comment: I can't tell you with certainty about the reasons for the blocking, I can only assume because I don't have a link to this website
If you can share a link to the website, then I can try it myself. Or I can write the code and you can try it yourself. What's best?

Comment: @BorisIvanov Being perfectly honest, the program I had made was for downloading images from a hentai site (example link https://nhentai.net/g/378446/ if you want one). Also, when accessing it just now it DID use Cloudflare for the first time I've noticed. If you can write code that can access any page on that site then I'd be quite grateful.

Comment: I added the code, I hope it will work for you too, in any case, if you find a better solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

#### So our task is: **How parse html-text with Java on website that's protected by cloudflare.**

The speed of my method may not meet your requirements, because not every API call is successful. However, it works:

We will use Proxy Api web scrapping [SCRAPPER-API](https://www.scraperapi.com/)
with the free version, registration takes no more than 5 minutes. We need to get an API key (We can use any one if it's better for you)

1. First step create util class:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class Downloader {

    public static String downloadText(String url) throws IOException {
        return downloadText(url, "utf-8");
    }

    public static String downloadTextWithHeaders(String url, Map<String, String> headers) throws IOException {
        return downloadTextWithHeaders(url, "utf-8", headers);
    }

    public static String downloadTextWithHeaders(String url, String encoding, Map<String, String> headers) throws IOException {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
        }

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        if ("gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding())) {
            in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
        }

        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }
    }

    public static String downloadText(String url, String encoding) throws IOException {

        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
        InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();

        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create SiteScrapper class:

```
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Content;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ru.mtgsale.common.Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SiteScrapper {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiteScrapper.class);
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 30000;
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOU_API_KEY";  //api key from ScrapperApi

    private final boolean direct; // need for turn ON/OFF proxy
    private final Map<String, String> HEADERS = new HashMap<>();
    private final Checker checker; // does the page contain the required text

    public interface Checker {
        boolean check(String pageText);
    }

    public SiteScrapper(boolean direct, Checker checker) throws IOException {
        this.direct = direct;  
        this.checker = checker; 

        HEADERS.put("Accept", "*/*");
        HEADERS.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        HEADERS.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
    }

    public String downloadText(String url) throws IOException {
        return downloadText(url, null);
    }
    
    public String downloadText(String url, String encoding) throws IOException {

        if (direct) {
            if (encoding == null) {
                return Downloader.downloadTextWithHeaders(url, HEADERS);
            } else {
                return Downloader.downloadTextWithHeaders(url, encoding, HEADERS);
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                url = url.replace("+", "%2B");
                String uri = "https://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&url=" + url;

                log.info("Starting parse link: " + url);
                Request request = Request.Get(uri).connectTimeout(TIMEOUT).socketTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                Content content = Executor.newInstance()
                        .execute(request)
                        .returnContent();

                String res = encoding == null ? content.asString() : content.asString(Charset.forName(encoding));

                if (checker != null && !checker.check(res)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Access denied");
                }

                log.info("Success, link: " + url + " parsed");
                return res;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("Can't parse link: " + url + ", trying again...");
                Utils.sleep(1000);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

3. Last step you can call the Scrapper method:

```
SiteScrapper scrapper = new SiteScrapper(false, checker -> true);
String htmlText = scrapper.downloadText(YOU URL);
```

How to use checker:

```
private static final SiteScrapper.Checker checker = pageText -> pageText.contains("<a href=\"something\">"); //any html text what you need
```

Comment: I would like to test this, but I can't seem to find any place to download the "org.apache.http.client.fluent." imports. It seems to be no longer supported and I can't even find the old source code anywhere. If possible, I'd rather not depend on third party libraries at all (a pet peeve of mine) but it's been frustrating enough that I'm willing to do so. Do you happen to know where I can find the library to download?

Comment: This can be taken [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/fluent-hc)
I think the code can be rewritten with another library, but it will take me some more time.

Comment: Probably not worth your time to rewrite it. However, when I tried to run it it failed to ever finish. After one minute of execution I interrupted it. Here https://justpaste.it/8w1t4 is the log of that minute of execution

Comment: you need change "YOU_API_KEY" to api key from scrapper api

Comment: Take it from your personal account: http://joxi.ru/GrqKzqvSzKbJ92

Comment: I got an api key (sorry for forgetting). It did work the first time I tried it (took like 20 seconds though) but then it failed the next 5 I tried (https://justpaste.it/9j7ze rather short logs). There is also the fact that I'd rather not completely outsource the whole process to a third party (which seems to happen here). In that case I'd rather make a simple web browser that can be made to automatically do the same things I do manually.